# How to setup lifecycle to delete folders under s3 bucket using boto3

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am facing issue creating an object lifecycle to delete all folders which are older than 2 days using boto 3.
My s3 structure is as follows:

```
    S3 bucket name : test
    S3 folders under test bucket : day1, day2, day3
    S3 files under each folder :
    test/day1/file1.txt
    test/day2/file2.txt
    test/day3/file3.txt
```

I want to have a lifecycle which deletes all folders that are older than 2 days. I figured out something which has:

```
    import boto3
    from boto.s3.lifecycle import Lifecycle,Rule,Transitions,Expiration
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    bucket = s3.Bucket('test')
    expiration = Expiration(days=2)
    rule = Rule(id='deletetestfold',status='Enabled', expiration=expiration)
    lifecycle = Lifecycle()
    lifecycle.append(rule)
```

But this 2nd half of the code uses boto and NOT boto3. Is there a way we can accomplish the lifecycle for deleting folders older than 2 days using **boto3**
Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration) method.

Comment: @errate isnt put deprecated?

Comment: @Austin Ah, I haven't noticed until you mentioned... Time to prepare my code too for this changes ^^ Updated my answer too :)

Comment: To make the conversation more clear: put_bucket_lifecycle is deprecated, but put_bucket_lifecycle_configuration is ok